# OpenGL conversion of rgb to YUV image using frag shader

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4

I'm trying to use openlGL to convert my rgb image which is in (*buf) into a YUV image. Using a fragment shader. Currently I am only calculating the Y part of the image in the shader. I was wondering how to get this Y value back into my c++ code and potentially into an array or buffer. Or if anyone could direct me to how variables in the shader communicate with c++ code.

```
int main()
{


   void* buf //assume buf has the rgb image.

    SDL_Surface *Win=NULL;
    SDL_Event evt;
    int i;
    GLhandleARB FSHandle,PHandle;
    char *s;

    const char *FProgram=
            "uniform sampler2DRect rgba;\n"
            "void main(void) {\n"
            "float Y;\n"
            "vec4 new_rgba = texture2DRect(rgba, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);\n"

            "new_rgba.rgba = vec4(new_rgba.g, new_rgba.b, new_rgba.a , 1);\n"

            "Y = ((55.0 * new_rgba.r + 183.0 * new_rgba.g + 18.0 * new_rgba.b + 128.0)* 256.0);\n"

            "gl_FragColor = new_rgba;"
            "}\n";


    if(!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) {

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,1);

        Win=SDL_SetVideoMode(B_WIDTH,B_HEIGHT,32,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_ANYFORMAT|SDL_OPENGL);

        if(Win) {
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(0,B_WIDTH,0,B_HEIGHT,-1,1);
            glViewport(0,0,B_WIDTH,B_HEIGHT);
            glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
            //glColor3f(1.0,0.84,0.0);
            glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST);

            /* Set up program objects. */
            PHandle=glCreateProgramObjectARB();
            FSHandle=glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);

            /* Compile the shader. */
            glShaderSourceARB(FSHandle,1,&FProgram,NULL);
            glCompileShaderARB(FSHandle);

            /* Print the compilation log. */
            glGetObjectParameterivARB(FSHandle,GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB,&i);
            s=new char(32768);
            glGetInfoLogARB(FSHandle,32768,NULL,s);
            printf("Compile Log: %s\n", s);
            delete[] s;

            /* Create a complete program object. */
            glAttachObjectARB(PHandle,FSHandle);
            glLinkProgramARB(PHandle);

            /* And print the link log. */
            s=new char(32768);
            glGetInfoLogARB(PHandle,32768,NULL,s);
            printf("Link Log: %s\n", s);
            delete[] s;

            /* Finally, use the program. */
            glUseProgramObjectARB(PHandle);


            /* This might not be required, but should not hurt. */
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

            /* Select texture unit 1 as the active unit and bind the U texture. */
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,1);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_DECAL);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,0,GL_RGBA8,1920,1080,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, buf);

            i=glGetUniformLocationARB(PHandle,"rgba");
            glUniform1iARB(i,1);

            /* Simple loop, just draws the image and waits for quit. */
            while(!Quit) {
                if(SDL_PollEvent(&evt)) {
                    switch(evt.type) {
                    case  SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    case  SDL_QUIT:
                        Quit=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                /* Draw image (again and again). */

                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2i(0,1080);
                glVertex2i(0,0);
                glTexCoord2i(1920,1080);
                glVertex2i(B_WIDTH,0);
                glTexCoord2i(1920,0);
                glVertex2i(B_WIDTH,B_HEIGHT);
                glTexCoord2i(0,0);
                glVertex2i(0,B_HEIGHT);
                glEnd();

                /* Flip buffers. */

                glFlush();
                SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

                SDL_Delay(50);
            } /* while(!Quit) */

            /* Clean up before exit. */

            glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
            glDeleteObjectARB(PHandle);



        } else {
            fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create primary surface. \"%s\".\n",SDL_GetError());
        }
        SDL_Quit();
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Initialisation failed. \"%s\".\n",SDL_GetError());
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You are computing `Y` in the fragment shader, but it's never output. There is literally no way to get that value back, and the GLSL compiler may strip it away since it's not output. You may need to use multiple draw buffers (GL 3.0 / GLSL 1.30 feature) to do this. While you're at it, re-write your code to use 2.0's core GLSL instead of the ancient `GL_ARB_shader_objects` extension.

Comment: Ok I'll google 2.0 Core GLSL. And I'm still very new to glsl I would you be able to explain how to get the output Y or write that Y into a file? That's what my end gold is, to write the Y into a file rather than on the window.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't lnow anything about files. The fragment shader outputs to a frame buffer, and you can of course read those contents back after rendering.

Comment: @user2111864: Typically you're just emitting the YUV values through the fragment's RGB channels, i.e. Y goes into R, U goes into G, V goes into B. Remember that RGB are just arbitrary letters and only for convenience happen to coincide with the first letters of the colors which are emitted by the subpixels those channels map to by default. But those are scalars which can mean literally anything.

Comment: @datenwolf ooh I didn't know that. My follow up question would be: I essentially want to output gl_FragColor = vec4(Y) ...like that?

Comment: @user2111864: Yes, exactly like that. Just be aware that for non float format render targets the values of each channel are clamped to the range [0, 1], so if you need values outside that range you may have to bias-scale them (`vec4(…)*s + b` replacing s and b with the scale and bias values). For example to map the range [-2, 2] you'd use s=0.25, b=0.5

Comment: @datenwolf I've never head of scale and bias. How would I calculate values from [0, 255]

Comment: @datenwolf: Well, each vector element going into gl_FragColor is clamped to [0,1]; unless you're writing to a float format render target. yes I know, this seems counterintuitive, as the the value range [0,1] can be represented only with floating point in the fragment shader. However if the target image is of type, say uint8_t, then the value range [0,1] in the fragment shader is automatically mapped to the range [0,255] in the destination image.